# Timestamp in telemetry_view.csv file (generated by jprofiler)

Tags: jprofiler

I profile some application with the sampling method with a delay of 5 ms (jprofiler 7):

JProfiler> Offline profiling mode. 
JProfiler> Protocol version 39 
... 
JProfiler> **Using sampling (5 ms)** 
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time 
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled 
JProfiler> Saving snapshot memory_view.0.jps ...  
JProfiler> Done.

Then I exported the result into a csv file:

"**Time [s]**","Committed size","Free size","Used size" 
**0.0**,38912000,26542000,12370000 
**1.0**,38912000,21710000,17202000 
**2.0**,38912000,10829000,28083000 
3.0,55168000,28363000,26805000

Here I am surprised since the csv file contains one measure per second while the sampling was done every 5 ms.

Does exist a way to increase the number of outputs in the csv file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have exported a telemetry view. Telemetry views are always sampled with a 1s interval. The sampling interval for CPU profiling is only relevant for call stack measurements and the CPU views.